# How to create this new column?

Tags: r, tidyverse

With {tidyverse}, I'm trying to create a new variable with advanced condition.
Here's my example :
Many thanks in advance

```
mydf <- tibble(
  siren = c("a","b"),
  region_impl = c("24","11"),
  nbeta_reg24 = c(3,1),
  nbeta_reg11= c(5,2)
)

# What I want
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  siren region_impl nbeta_reg24 nbeta_reg11 nbeta_reg
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1 a     24                    3           5         3
2 b     11                    1           2         2
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the condition here?

Comment: I tried something like this `mydf %>% 
  mutate(
    nbeta_reg = mydf$nbeta_reg24[mydf$region_impl=="24"])
  )`

Comment: How did you get 2 for `nbeta_reg`

Comment: The new `nbeta_reg` column must take for example the value of the nbeta_reg24 column if the `region_impl` column is equal to "24" (same explanation for "11")

Comment: Yes I need `2` for the 2nd row with `region_impl` is equal to `11` (=the value of `nbeta_reg11` column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one vectorized option -

```
mydf <- data.frame(mydf)
mydf$nbeta_reg <- mydf[cbind(1:nrow(mydf), match(paste0('nbeta_reg', 
                       mydf$region_impl), names(mydf)))]
mydf

#  siren region_impl nbeta_reg24 nbeta_reg11 nbeta_reg
#1     a          24           3           5         3
#2     b          11           1           2         2
```

Using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(nbeta_reg = get(paste0('nbeta_reg', region_impl))) %>%
  ungroup

#  siren region_impl nbeta_reg24 nbeta_reg11 nbeta_reg
#  <chr> <chr>             <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 a     24                    3           5         3
#2 b     11                    1           2         2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `select` in `tidverse`

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(nbetareg = select(cur_data(), ends_with(region_impl))[[1]]) %>%
    ungroup
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  siren region_impl nbeta_reg24 nbeta_reg11 nbetareg
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 a     24                    3           5        3
2 b     11                    1           2        2
```